# ruby on rails action mailer not receiving emails to arrays from a yaml file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

I have an issue where i am able to send email via the mailer for a hardcoded array.
But the email does not go through for an array picked up from config.yml

Here is my config.yml

```
company:
  email:
    - user1@company.com
    - User1.Lastname@company.com
    - User2.Lastname@company.com
```

This is my mailer class:

```
class ReportMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default :from => "donotreply@company.com"


  def send_report(company, file)

      mail(:to=> "#{CONFIG[company]['email']}", :subject => "Daily  Report")
    end
  end
end
```

when run it in my rails console & view the logs, seems like everything was executed fine but I did not receive my email:

```
[DEBUG] 2016-04-21 18:21:29 :: Date: Thu, 21 Apr 2016 18:21:29 -0400
From: donotreply@merchantlink.com
to: ["user1@company.com", "User1.Lastname@company.com","User2.Lastname@company.com"]
 ...
 ...

 [INFO] 2016-04-21 18:21:29 ::
Sent mail to ["user1@company.com", "User1.Lastname@company.com", "User2.Lastname@company.com"]
```

If i change my code & replace it with hardcoded array  instead of reading from config.yml it works fine.

Am i reading the yaml array wrong?

Comment: you are passing a string to `to` here, instead of an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As correctly pointed out in the comment by @Alfie, you are passing a stringified array to `to:`.

`CONFIG[company]['email']` returns an array, then string interpolation calls `to_s` on it and you end up with

```
"['user1@company.com', 'User1.Lastname@company.com','User2.Lastname@company.com']"
```

Just pass in the array without inserting it into a string:

```
mail(:to=> CONFIG[company]['email'], :subject => "Daily  Report")
```